# Prepared Statement returning partial records i.e 3 whereas sql developer for the same query returns all records i.e 5

Tags: java, sql, oracle, ibatis

I am encountering a very strange issue

Java code:

```
preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(strSql);
resultset = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

While debugging I tried to find what is the SQL, which was:

```
SELECT JOBLOG.JOB_EVENT_CODE,JOBLOG.LOG_DATETIME,JOBLOG.MESSAGE_TEXT,B.ITEM_DESC1
FROM JOB_LOG JOBLOG,REF_DATA_ITEM_MASTER B WHERE JOBLOG.BATCH_ID = ? 
AND JOBLOG.JOB_EVENT_CODE = B.ITEM_ID AND B.CATEGORY_ID = 105
ORDER BY JOBLOG.JOB_LOG_ID ASC
```

Parameter was substituted as **20021854**

The above query when run through java code has resultset size as 3

```
resultset = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

But if I run the same query in sqldeveloper I have 5 records as output

```
SELECT JOBLOG.JOB_EVENT_CODE,JOBLOG.LOG_DATETIME,JOBLOG.MESSAGE_TEXT,B.ITEM_DESC1 
FROM JOB_LOG JOBLOG,REF_DATA_ITEM_MASTER B
WHERE JOBLOG.BATCH_ID = 20021854 AND JOBLOG.JOB_EVENT_CODE = B.ITEM_ID AND B.CATEGORY_ID = 105
ORDER BY JOBLOG.JOB_LOG_ID ASC
```

To add more information my ORM is Ibatis. What could be the reason for this inconsistency

Answer (score 1):

Reasons that I can think of:

1. You inserted new rows in sql developer but have not commit your transaction , so only sql developer can see the new rows but not the java program (this is a common scenario :) )
2. You connect to 2 different database, please verify
3. You use setMaxRows in PreparedStatment?

Comment: its a select query, why would a commit be required?max row is not set, database is same

Comment: If you have insert / delete some rows in your sql developer and not commit it, then there will be such discrepancy (your java program will not see the inserted / deleted rows but your sql developer will see those "new" rows)

Answer (score 0):

What is often forgotten/overlooked especially with unions and views: [`getMoreResults`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getMoreResults()).

Here it does not look to be the case, but try:

```
do {
    ...
    try (ResultSet resultset = preparedStatement.executeQuery()) {
        ...
    }
} while (preparedStatement.getMoreResults());
```

However I would not be amazed, if the variable `resultset` is reused for another query (in not shown code), and hence prematurely run to the end. Declare it in a try-with-resources, as near as possible, with automatic `resultset.close()` even on return/exception.